# sql: insert value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a problem about inserting values into the table with sqlite.
supposing the table:

```
create table test 
{ 
    KeyName varchar(50) primary key,
    KeyValue varchar (255)

};
```

I want to insert data like `('john', 'friend')`, but I don't know whether the `'john'` existed.
Currently I solve it:

1. using select * where KeyName = "john"
2. according the result from list 1, I use insert or update;

I'd like to know whether there is better solution?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use insert or replace which replaces the record if it already exists.

so you query be INSERT OR REPLACE INTO

check this link : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html